# Intel MPI Gives 'channel initialization failed' error (mpirun)

Tags: linux, centos, cluster

I'm trying to setup a small cluster consisting of 3 servers. Their hardware is identical, and they are running CentOS 7. I'm using Intel's cluster compiler and MPI implementation. Everything is setup: I can ssh between all the nodes without a password, and I've shared the /opt directory with nfs, so `which mpicc` and `which mpirun` succeeds on all nodes. `mpirun -hosts node1 -n 24 /home/cluster/test` is the command I'm trying to run (test is compiled from test.c from the Intel compiler's test directory and is nfs shared between all nodes). It works fine on any single node, but if I try to run it across more than one node, I get:

```
[cluster@headnode ~]$ mpirun -hosts headnode -n 10 /home/cluster/test
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(784)...................: 
MPID_Init(1323).........................: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(141).....................: 
MPID_nem_tcp_post_init(644).............: 
MPID_nem_tcp_connect(1107)..............: 
MPID_nem_tcp_get_addr_port_from_bc(1342): Missing ifname or invalid host/port description in business card
```

Google has not given me any useful answers. I also setup a basic virtual machine cluster (CentOs 6.5) and I get the exact same error (so it's not a hardware problem).

Comment: What is the status of the firewalld service on your nodes?

Comment: It's disabled: CentOS 6 doesn't have it and iptables is also disabled. firewalld.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: maybe have the courtesy to up vote answers from folks who bothered to read the manual for products and look into your question that could have been solved with a quick something search.  you should have looked at the intel site before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Also check `/etc/hosts` and/or `dig headnode` to make sure that the host name can be resolved correctly from the node where the job is launched, if it can't I would check my poor cluster configuration before jumping to blame Intel MPI, I doubt this would work with OpenMPI or any other distribution if headnode can't be resoled correctly.  Further verifying that the port is open and accessible behind firewall and everything is configured correctly under SE Linux/other security features would be a logical first step since clearly the node is not accessible.

If you are having these issues and using Intel MPI then you should first do a ping-pong test with the Intel MPI Benchmarks(IMB), and analyze those results. I will let you look up the syntax for running that on the Intel website.  The tests and benchmarks Intel already wrote are better than anything you will come up with and will be much more useful when diagnosing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix it:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mpi-library-and-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-tips

Basically, add `-iface [network interface]` to the mpirun arguments, or add `export I_MPI_HYDRA_IFACE=[network interface]` to .bashrc

Comment: in the future maybe search the Intel Website before posting here since they have answered these questions about poor cluster configuration hundreds of times over